# Measuring the distance covered by a car

Tags: arduino-uno

I am currently working on developing an RC car that is controlled by an Arduino .

I would like to add a function that can calculate the distance covered by the car without using a GPS !

what are the available alternatives ?

Answer (score 3):

- The cheap and easy way. Doesn't work all the time though. This method uses an ultrasonic sensor (such as the HC-SR04). You mount it on the car's front bumper and calculate the distance from the car and the wall. Then from the start point, calculate how much distance has been covered. This method is flawed in the way that you cannot do this unless there is a wall in front of the car.
- Rotary encoder, put this on the wheel of your robot, then calculate the circonference of the wheels. Then calculate, with the number of rotation made and the circonference of the wheel, the distances that has been made. Some cars use this to calculate the cars speed. It is quite effective.